# How to run cron job when network is up?

Tags: cron-jobs, crontab, cron

I have some anacron jobs which run daily. The scripts update local bzr and git repositories. Naturally these scripts need working network connections. I'm on a laptop and often wired and wireless internet do not come up fast enough. This causes my cron job to time out when pulling the repositories =(

So:

**How to make sure the internet is up before running specific cron jobs? Or how to fail a job if there is no network, such that it is retried by anacron later again?**

Comment: What language? Bash, Python, Perl?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: Any will do. But I don't know Perl =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to help you there. Mind you, I haven't tested that code below  works but something very similar should.

```
# /etc/init/update-repositories.conf - Update local repos
#

description     "Update local repos"

# this will run the script section every time network is up
start on (net-device-up IFACE!=lo)

task

script
    svn up && git fetch
#   do some other useful stuff
end script
```

That pretty much it. You might want to add some code to check that it does not run very often. You might also want to add `start update-repositories` to your crontab, it'll make sure your update will happen if you are on the net constantly for a prolonged period of time.

Comment: This code will run *every* time a network interface comes up, including every time your wireless drops and reconnects. If you only want it to run once a day, add logic to place/check a timestamp.

Comment: Any idea whether this still works under systemd?

Answer (score 9):

I made a cron that did a ping test on a DNS server to ensure networking. Something like this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1 -i .2 -t 60 > /dev/null 2>&1
ONLINE=$?

if [ ONLINE -eq 0 ]; then
    #We're offline
else
    #We're online
fi
```

Recently I've used something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function check_online
{
    netcat -z -w 5 8.8.8.8 53 && echo 1 || echo 0
}

# Initial check to see if we are online
IS_ONLINE=check_online
# How many times we should check if we're online - this prevents infinite looping
MAX_CHECKS=5
# Initial starting value for checks
CHECKS=0

# Loop while we're not online.
while [ $IS_ONLINE -eq 0 ]; do
    # We're offline. Sleep for a bit, then check again

    sleep 10;
    IS_ONLINE=check_online

    CHECKS=$[ $CHECKS + 1 ]
    if [ $CHECKS -gt $MAX_CHECKS ]; then
        break
    fi
done

if [ $IS_ONLINE -eq 0 ]; then
    # We never were able to get online. Kill script.
    exit 1
fi

# Now we enter our normal code here. The above was just for online checking
```

This isn't the MOST elegant - I'm not sure how else to check via a simple command or file on the system, but this has worked for me when needed.

Comment: I had to encapsulate the `check_online` calls in $(), so `IS_ONLINE=$(check_online)`

Comment: I also suggest exitting with 0 at the end, this way one can reuse this script to call another one(s) like "./this_script.sh && ./cronJob.sh"

Answer (score 2):

You can talk to NetworkManager to see whether you are connected or not:

```
$state = $(dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager \
    org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.state 2>/dev/null \
| awk '/uint32/{print $2}')
if [ $state = 3 ]; then
    echo "Connected!"
else
    echo "Not connected!"
fi
```

Comment: Nice.  And ugly :)  Seems like a good candidate for implementation in some standard tool for convenient shell access, or via a Python API, so it was more readable and didn't use magic values like "3".

Answer (score 2):

Just to wrap up a couple of the options here into a single script:

```
#! /bin/bash
# This script checks that the interface is up, and that an internet connection is available
# It is based on code from http://askubuntu.com/questions/3299/how-to-run-cron-job-when-network-is-up
#
# Then it sleeps for a random number of seconds between 30 and 600.
# This is based on code from http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html
#
# Collated by @JonTheNiceGuy on 2015-10-15

function check_ipaddr
{
  # Here we look for an IP(v4|v6) address when doing ip addr
  # Note we're filtering out 127.0.0.1 and ::1/128 which are the "localhost" ip addresses
  # I'm also removing fe80: which is the "link local" prefix

  ip addr | \
  grep -v 127.0.0.1 | \
  grep -v '::1/128' | \
  grep -v 'inet6 fe80:' | \
  grep -E "inet [[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+|inet6" | \
  wc -l
}

function check_google
{
  netcat -z -w 5 8.8.8.8 53 && echo 1 || echo 0
}

until [ `check_ipaddr` -gt 1 ]; do
  sleep 2
done

until [ `check_google` -eq 1 ]; do
  sleep 2
done

sleep $((RANDOM%570+30))
```

I plan to maintain this script at https://gist.github.com/JonTheNiceGuy/5cf4a23c8f2f755a9ca4

Answer (score 1):

To expand on nixternal, the `fping` binary is excellent for that.  You can cook it up in one-liners as in

```
$ fping -q yoo.mama && echo yes
$ fping -q www.google.com && echo yes
yes
$
```

As you see, yoo.mama does not like me but Google does.  In crontab, you'd do something like

```
5 5 * * *  root   fping -q google.com && /some/script/I/want --to --run
```

Comment: That won't run the command later if the network is down.  How could that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a shell script that does what you need, ie. checks for network connection and then fires off the updates. Then call the script from cron.

Answer (score 0):

```
until ifconfig eth | grep -qE 'addr:([[:digit:]]+\.?)+'; do
   sleep 2
done
```

Comment: This answer doesn't quite explain what the user should be doing to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've defined a `bash` alias to answer this question:

```
alias netstate='ip link show | egrep -q '\''UP,LOWER_UP.* state UP'\'' && echo UP || echo DOWN'
```

You could use it, or process the output of `ip link show` yourself.

To handle "net goes down/net comes up" see my `net-o-matic` script at [net-o-matic](https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git)

Answer (score 0):

I found `ping` solutions gave me network errors which spammed my logs unless I laboriously directed errors to /dev/null

Network Manager can be used:

```
if nmcli general | grep "^connected" >/dev/null
then
   echo "nmcli connected"
fi
```