# How can I set mac address using the command line in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager

With Ubuntu 14.04 when I wanted to connect to a network using a different mac address I would run the following commands

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo ifconfig $interface down
sudo macchanger -m <mac_addresse> $interface
sudo ifconfig $interface up
sudo service network-manager start
```

This would assign a new mac address which persisted after network-manager was restarted and a new connection to the network was made.
now, on Ubuntu 16.04, after running those same commands using

- `sudo macchanger -m 00:60:1B:EB:F8:73 wlp2s0`

I then restart `network-manager` but **not connected to the network yet**,  the new macchanger assigned mac address persists i.e.

```sh
% nmcli dev show wlp2s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:60:1B:EB:F8:73
      address assigned by macchanger -->^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
```

but the moment I connect to a network, the mac address is reset back to the original hardware mac address. after making connection to the network

```
% nmcli  dev show wlp2s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E0:06:E6:A3:2C:A7
   mac is back to original hardware  -->^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     lowfi
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         92.10.26.193/20
IP4.GATEWAY:                            92.10.24.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             202.8.44.226
IP4.DNS[2]:                             202.8.47.10
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

How can I make the macchanger assigned mac address persist when connecting to the network using the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wlan and macchanger](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267338/wlan-and-macchanger)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use nmcli to temporarily change your mac address:

```
nmcli connection modify --temporary <connection_name> 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address 00:60:1B:EB:F8:73
nmcli connection up <connection_name>
```