# I dont understad nmcli connection modify --temporary 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address 00:60:1B:EB:F8:73

Tags: networking, internet

This is from [How can I set mac address using the command line in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775057/how-can-i-set-mac-address-using-the-command-line-in-ubuntu-16-04) , where I cannot contact the_velour_fog

I have this same problem but im stuck with the solution adonis proposed:

```
nmcli connection modify --temporary 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address 00:60:1B:EB:F8:73
```

Is this a command? What do I write instead of `connection_name`? I don't know where to find it.

```
nmcli connection up
```

If this is a whole command, do I `&&` between them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "nmcli" is a command.  It's a shortened version of NetworkManager command-line interface.  You can find it by using the "which" command, like this (but it should already be in your PATH)

```
[jcall@laptop ~]$ which nmcli
/usr/bin/nmcli
```

The 'connection name' will be something you created previously.  Your connections could be created from the command-line, but I usually just use the GUI to create them (especially wireless connections.)  You can list your connections with the command "nmcli connection show" or the abbreviated way "nmcli c s"  Here is an example of my connections...

```
[jcall@laptop ~]$ nmcli connection show
NAME              UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE 
Home_WiFi         c1c95bd9-78f3-4764-9922-971339702735  802-11-wireless  --     
Hotel_WiFi        921ad0bf-e18e-4d90-87d9-0f1c852c3dc7  802-11-wireless  --     
Google Starbucks  d5242485-ebd6-4152-a839-eaedacc49b4a  802-11-wireless  --     
enp0s25           6c6036d5-4739-3540-ac21-bf7a04669ed6  802-3-ethernet   --
```

Finally, you need to execute the commands in order, one after the other.  You could use && to do that, if you want to create a long single-line command.  I usually just create a small script file to make things easier.  Here is my example.

```
[jcall@laptop ~]$ cat ~/bin/mac-changer.sh 
#!/bin/bash

DEV=wlp3s0
NEWMAC=9c:d9:17:2e:ae:5f

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "You forgot to tell me which network to connect to..."
  echo "Please run \`nmcli con show\` for ideas..."
  exit 1
fi

if $(nmcli -t -f NAME con show | grep -q $1)
then
  nmcli connection modify --temporary $1 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address $NEWMAC
  nmcli connection up $1
else
  echo "Error: $1 is not a known network.  Please run \`nmcli con show\` for ideas..."
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either do a one whole command with && or in order. < Connection name > is the name of the wifi you are currently connected too. You dont have to input <> just the string name ex. MyWifi

Comment: You really should explain **how** to solve that problem - it will take some time :-)