# Why doesn't my Wi-Fi adapter show up as wlan0 in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, ifconfig

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a separate HDD, and I noticed two oddities:

- Whereas on 14.04 (on my main HDD) my USB Wi-Fi dongle shows up as `wlan0`, on 16.04 it shows up as `wlx112233445566`. (Real MAC redacted)
- Also, using the `hw ether` parameter to change the MAC address doesn't work on 16.04.

Here's the relevant output from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: Apparently you can change the MAC of a specific interface in 16.04 with nmcli as explained here: http://askubuntu.com/a/775102/527751

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of recently, Ubuntu (well, `systemd`) now uses something called [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). Essentially, this means that non-permanent network interfaces (ie, USB interfaces) now have a name in the form of `enx<MAC_ADDR>`or `wlx<MAC_ACCR>` (or similar), so that any scripts and systems depending on that *specific* device will have 100% confidence that it's targeting the right device.

Other naming conventions will allow for the device to be referred to by physical location or any other form of permanently identifying value. Specifically, any of these values can be used to generate an interface name (with the best being chosen):

> - Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board
>     devices (example: `eno1`)
> - Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: `ens1`)
> - Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: `enp2s0`)
> - Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: `enx78e7d1ea46da`)
> - Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: `eth0`)

In the past, interface names weren't assigned in a "sane" fashion -- some systems used pseudo-permanent names (`wlan1` for a device with this MAC), others assigned them on a first-come first-serve basis. If you still prefer this scheme of doing things (or just hate persistent names because `systemd` is doing it), it's possible to reverse it by adding `net.ifnames=0` to your boot arguments.

You should still be able to fake the MAC address of the device by using the Connection Editor, but `hw ether` will no longer work as the MAC address is a piece of the device's identifier/name.

Comment: *"You should still be able to fake the MAC address of the device by using the Connection Editor"* - That never worked in 14.04. I always had to use `hw ether`.

Comment: revrting the change for internal interfaces should be done with

Answer (score 4):

> it's possible to reverse it by adding net.ifnames=0 to your boot arguments.

That won't be enough to change the name for the USB interface...
You also need to play around with `80-net-setup-link.rules`

1) Copy the current rule to your `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory

```
sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

2) Create a symlink to send it to `/dev/null` to disable it:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

for more information check this thread: [How to revert USB wifi interface name (from wlxXXXXXXXXXXXX to wlanX)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826325/how-to-revert-usb-wifi-interface-name-from-wlxxxxxxxxxxxxx-to-wlanx/826614#826614)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is as simple as a design change, the numbers are now different. It's not a fault. My LAN, for example, was eth0 in 14.04 (and still is in some other distros) but is enp0s25 in 16.04.

This naming convention has no impact on performance and i would not worry about it.

EDIT : Kaz Wolfe gives a more thorough explanation.