# Ubuntu 17.04: how to rename a USB network interface based on Path? (NOT based on MAC)

Tags: networking, 17.04, systemd, udev

No, this ain't a duplicate of [Why doesn't my Wi-Fi adapter show up as wlan0 in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865916/why-doesnt-my-wi-fi-adapter-show-up-as-wlan0-in-16-04), as this explains how to restore `eth0` naming, but not how to individually name a specific interface.

I don't want to assign based on MAC match. **All I need is to assign name *based on the USB path*.**

When I plug in an USB network adapter, on Ubuntu 17.04 it gets assigned a network interface name based on its MAC, such as `encx000000000000`. Now I would like to rename it to something more telling, based on its ID_PATH=`pci-000:02:03.0-usb-0:1:1.0`. In particular, I **don't want to match based on MAC address**.
The rationale is that after interface replacement all would break down, but if someone simply replaces network interface hardware so that the new hardware is in the same place as the old one, the system will tuck on without needing IT and reconfiguration support.

So I created a file `/etc/systemd/network/50-my-island.link`:

```
[Match]
Path=pci-000:02:03.0-usb-0:1:1.0
[Link]
Name=island0
```

Unfortunately, the name is never assigned. Using `udevadm info` I can see that there is `ID_NET_NAME=island0` set, but it does not apply. Trying `NamePolicy=` or `NamePolicy=name` under the `[Link]` section doesn't help either.

I'm lost! How can I assign my name in the .link file to my USB network adapter? Is this possible at all without resorting to some udev rule? Why then having .link files at all when they don't seem to work in my case? Where did I make an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my Wi-Fi adapter show up as wlan0 in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865916/why-doesnt-my-wi-fi-adapter-show-up-as-wlan0-in-16-04)

Comment: `sudo touch /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` now causes the USB network interface to become `eth0`. Slightly better, but still wrong!

Comment: Did anyone read my question carefully? I asked how to rename an interface based on its **path**, not it's MAC. All dupes here link to restoring old naming or assigning by MAC. Is this so difficult to understand?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I finally figured out myself what really is happening.

Alas, the problem I'm seeing that renaming **USB**-based network interfaces doesn't work is actually caused by the udev rule `/lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules` on Ubuntu/Debian (and thus also Raspbian). The culprit in it is here:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", NAME=="", \
  ATTR{address}=="?[014589cd]:*", \
  TEST!="/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules", \
  TEST!="/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link", \
    IMPORT{builtin}="net_id", NAME="$env{ID_NET_NAME_MAC}"
```

Notice how this specific rule checks for **`/etc`**`/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` to be present; if it's not, then `NAME` will be set to a MAC48-based name, and the later default install rule **`/lib`**`/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` will never get a chance to assign `NAME`. Now that's sad. Again.

In order to enable the ability to assign user-defined names to **USB** network interfaces, we need to have **`/etc`**`/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`, as this is the rule set `73-usb-net-by-mac.rules` checks against before assigning `NAME`.

This means that simply linking from `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` to `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules` is needed in order to avoid that user-assigned network interface names get ignored any longer.

```
sudo ln -s /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

Reboot. Done.

Please note that a side-effect of the way `73-usb-net-by-mac.rules` is set up, this causes all USB-based network interfaces to assume "old" naming `eth0`, et cetera, unless explicitly named in a `.link` file.

I don't know why the rules have been written as they are, as it would be fine to have MAC-based naming for all USB network adapters not explicitly named. On a second thought ... *no*, using MAC48-based names does not make any sense, unless you happen to label all your USB network dongles and constantly swap them around; but maybe the MAC-based names are used with docking stations, where it actually would make sense...?

Comment: `reboot` step is not compatible with Unix ideology.

Answer (score 4):

As per [this thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/07/msg01453.html)
and especially this paragraph:

> Custom net interface naming 
>   ... 
>   The name of the rules file needs to
>   have a prefix smaller than "80" so that it runs before
>   /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules, and should have a prefix
>   bigger than "75" so that it runs after 75-net-description.rules and
>   thus you can use matches on ID_VENDOR and similar properties. ...

I did create this file : `/etc/udev/rules.d/76-netnames.rules`

with this content

```
# USB device by path
# get ID_PATH if not present yet
ENV{ID_PATH}=="", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_PATH}=="*-usb-0:1.*", NAME="eth%n"
```

it is working fine, without the workaround you provided.

I created this file in a debian preseed.cfg to set my target network configuration in a Debian fully automated installation.
Doing this on an Intel NUC, my internal NIC is now named `eno1` by Debian 9.5 (stretch)

Comment: Wow!  *Excellent* first answer! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**

Comment: how is this supposed to work when there is `lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules` where 73<75?

Comment: This is basically an alternate solution which requires users to configure `udev`(!) rules. My original question was to use the *systemd-based* link configuration mechanism and trying to avoid fiddling with udev rules. The rationale for going with systemd is to keep configurations confined to a *single* mechanism which might be easier to others to understand, more so as network configuration cannot and does not belong to udev.

Comment: TheDiveO, the rules is applied between 75 and 80 and it does work.
I undestand your point. Using udev is pretty common though (I used it for HDD device ownership for Oracle DB on Linux/Unix). A bit geeky but Debian stretch quite changed the naming rules of the nic cards.
I used this workaround first :

Comment: `Put "net.ifnames=0" into the kernel command line (e. g. in
    /etc/default/grub's GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, then run "update-grub")` but I changed it back after reading that the order of the interfaces was not stable.