# How to avoid same/duplicate MAC address for Huawei E3372h-607 4G modems?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, udev

I have four Huawei E3372h-607 4G modems in HiLink mode which means they are detected as 4 ethernet adapters:

```
...
[ 1378.768228] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
...
[ 1378.803419] cdc_ether 2-1:1.0 enx0c5b8f279a64: renamed from eth0
...
[ 1409.056051] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
...
[ 1409.076039] cdc_ether 2-2:1.0 rename9: renamed from eth0
...
[ 1409.056051] cdc_ether 2-3:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
...
[ 1409.076039] cdc_ether 2-3:1.0 rename10: renamed from eth0
...
[ 1409.056051] cdc_ether 2-4:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, CDC Ethernet Device, 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
...
[ 1409.076039] cdc_ether 2-4:1.0 rename11: renamed from eth0

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ ip link
...
17: enx0c5b8f279a64: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: rename18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: rename19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: rename20: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

There are two problems:

1. They have the same MAC addresses which cause problems when I want to bridge them to be used in a KVM virtual machine ([OpenMPTCProuter](https://www.openmptcprouter.com/) VM).
2. The name are changing for the second ethernet onwards after unplugging and replugging.

Based on [`systemd.link`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html)'s [`MACAddressPolicy`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html#MACAddressPolicy=), I wrote the following `/etc/systemd/network/01-huawei-e3372h.link` file:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
Driver=cdc_ether

[Link]
Description=Huawei E3372h-607 in HiLink mode
NamePolicy=path
MACAddressPolicy=random
```

**EDIT:**

```
$ ip link
...
14: enp0s20u4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:af:69:01:3e:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: enp0s20u3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:4a:48:f0:bb:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: enp0s20u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:2e:3d:9a:49:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: enp0s20u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:33:ba:8a:08:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Ok, so after checking `ip link`, the random MAC actually works. And after following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/947852/11392):

```
sudo ln -s /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

The rename also works. This question can be closed.

Comment: This shows, at most, two modems. What is the output of `lsusb` and `ifconfig`?

Comment: ups.. my bad.. I copy pasted.. will update the question..

Comment: Still no `ifconfig`

Comment: None of the devices have the same MAC address. Try again without the systemd .link file.